# Can't install lxml for python 3.8.1 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, lxml

I am on Windows 10 64-bit, in a venv.

```
Pip install lxml return
```

> Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

So I tried to use the appropriate .whl availlable [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) (lxml-4.5.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl) which leads to another error:

> lxml-4.5.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I tried to use pip.exe, pip3.exe, pip3.8.exe and the 64x and 32x bit versions of the .whl file without success

Am I missing something or is the Python 3.8 version of the package not compatible with Python 3.8.1?

Comment: I have just tried the same whl file on windows, 64bit python 3.8.1 and the whl file you metnioned installed just fine. Could you run `python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())"` and post the result?

Comment: Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, != 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you probably have an older version of python alongside 3.8 and when you install the package it references the older one. You can try deleting all python versions and installing Python 3.8 again

Answer (score 0):

I used deactivate to get out of venv mode, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use "pip3 install lxml" and you will get it installed. Make sure you have updated pip3 version. You can install it by "easy_install -U pip3". Let me know in case of issues.